# node.js and socket.io - what is sessions.httpRequest

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm working on learning how to implement socket.io and I came across this code in someone else's project and I cant find any documentation on it anywhere.

Can someone please explain it to me or shoot me a link to the proper documentation.

Thanks

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var io = require('socket.io');
var url = require('url');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var session = require('sessions');
var user_session = new session();

//create the server 
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response){
    user_session.httpRequest(request, response, function(errors, session){...
```

(my best guess is that it has to do with creating an individual session/socket/something for an individual user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is the GitHub page for the `sessions` module (which I had not heard about before either):

https://github.com/dresende/node-sessions